# Conversion from 'char' to non-scalar type 'Vector<char>' error thrown unknown reason

Tags: c++, vector, g++, compiler-errors

Error Thrown Unknown Reason

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()  
{  
    vector<char> shape = ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a');  
    return(0);  
}
```

that one line with the vector throws this error that I've never seen before nor can figure out...

:: g++ TicTacToe.cpp -o TTT
TicTacToe.cpp: In function `int main()':

TicTacToe.cpp:5: error: conversion from`char' to non-scalar type `Vector' requested

See in each tic-tac-toe box it will start as _ and then go to either X or O, I'm doing this without a graphics library so its terminal graphics.

Answer (score 2):

If all value are the same you can use the following constructor of the `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> shape( 9, 'a' );
```

If part or all values are distinct you can use another constructor as follows:

```
static const char ini[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i' };
std::vector<char> shape( ini, ini+sizeof(ini) );
```

Or

```
static const char ini[] = "abcdefghi";
std::vector<char> shape( ini, ini+sizeof(ini)-1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Such vector initialization isn't possible in current C++. You can use :

```
vector<char> shape(9, 'a');
```

which will have the desired effect (create a vector of size 9 where all elements are set to `'_'`).

If [boost](http://www.boost.org) is an option, [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) provides the kind of syntax you wanted to achieve initially, although in this particular case using the appropriate `std::vector` constructor is largely sufficient.

Comment: hehe i was mixin array and vector huh   ;p

Answer (score 0):

vector doesn't have such a constructor. See the valid [constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/).

Answer (score 0):

The [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/) class has the following constructor:

```
explicit vector( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator&=Allocator());
```

Using which you can do:

```
vector<char> shape (9,'a');
```